# Update Multi Row At One Time

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM options;
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | value   |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | aa   | a value |
|  2 | bb   | b value |
|  3 | cc   | c value |
|  4 | dd   | d value |
|  5 | ee   | e value |
+----+------+---------+
```

I have an options table.

I want to Update multi row in same query (with where case name).

Suppose I update options.name **aa** and **bb** at one time. It's update like

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | value   |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | aa   |aa value |
|  2 | bb   |bb value |
+----+------+---------+
```

Comment: what did you try ? write query?

Comment: I cant figur out any query for it ..... PLEASE HELP

Comment: what do u want? replace a with aa?

Comment: in update query if you same value put in aa and bb then you can otherwise you can write saparte query for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Update options
Set value = name + ' value'
where name in ('aa', 'bb')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **UPDATE WHERE .. IN**

```
UPDATE options
SET value = 'any value'
WHERE name IN ('aa', 'bb)
```

Comment: it is put same value for all name('aa','bb')